# Are two different variables in two different files assigned same values refer to same object

Tags: python

Lets say i have a file 'file1.py'
Its code is

```
import time
a = 10
print(id(a))
time.sleep(10)
```

I have another file say 'file2.py'
Its code is

```
b = 10
print(id(b))
```

I run the `file1.py` and it created an object that is holding value `10`. Now while the code in first file is sleep for 10sec i run the `file2.py` and now the question is will the `b` will also refer to the same object created in `a` or it will create another object for itself.
However the object created in a has not been dead yet.
If both the `id(a) != id(b)` then how do python manage to create and separate objects for different files at different locations in memory. Why python is not assigning `b` to also refer to the same object created in `a` case as both `a` and `b` are assigned same values.

Comment: I’m confused by the underlying assumptions here. You’re saying two different programs use different areas of memory? … Yes, that’s how it works…

Answer (score 0):

The execution of two different python applications is completely independent (code wise). Maybe you should read about Scopes to understand variable declaration inside of python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp